# Differentiabily of a complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

The function $f(z)=|z|^{2}+i.\bar{z}+1$ is differentiable at

(a) $i$

(b) $1$

(c) $-i$

(d) no point of $\mathbb C$.

We know the derivative of $\bar z$ does not exists at any point. So the function is not differentiable no point of $\mathbb C$.

Am I right or wrong? Please suggest me about this with justification because I am confused for the given answer.

Comment: What $z^-$ means?

Comment: '_' denotes the $bar$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(z)=x^2+y^2+y+1+ix$ where $z=x+iy$

$u=x^2+y^2+y+1$ ; $v=x$

Compute the partial derivatives and check the Cauchy-Riemann equations

$u_x=2x,u_y=2y+1;v_y=0;v_x=1$

which is satisfied only when $x=0,y=-1$ i.e option c

Also the partial derivatives are continuous at $-i$

Comment: From your argument we can conclude that the function is analytic at $-i$, not differentiability.

Comment: You have made a mistake in $f(z)$.

Comment: what are the sufficient conditions for differentiablity @Panja.S.

Comment: where is the mistake @AlexSilva

Comment: Sorry, You're right. It was my mistake. Could you edit anything for undo the downvote?

Comment: @learnmore In real analysis sufficient condition is "both $f_{x}$ & $f_{y}$ exists & one of them is continuous".

Comment: please check the conditions of differentiability in any standard book of complex analysis @Panja.S.

Comment: all right check yourself again in future while you are downvoting